# Can eclipse extract a second class in class file to its own file

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I often refactor code first by creating an inner class inside the class I'm working on--When I'm done, I move the entire thing into a new class file.  This makes refactoring code into the new class extremely easy because A) I'm only dealing with a single file, and B) I don't create new files until I have a pretty good idea of the name/names (Sometimes it ends up as more than one class).

Is there any way Eclipse can help me with the final move?  I should just be able to tell it what package I want the class in, it can figure out the filename from the class name and the directory from the package.

This seems like a trivial refactor and really obvious, but I can't figure out the keystrokes/gestures/whatever to make it happen.  I've tried dragging, menus, context menus, and browsing through the keyboard shortcuts.

Anyone know this one?

[edit] These are already "Top Level" classes in this file, not inner classes, and "Move" doesn't seem to want to create a new class for me. This is the hard way that I usually do it--involves going out, creating an empty class, coming back and moving.  I would like to do the whole thing in a single step.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm sorry I gave the wrong answer before. I rechecked, and it didn't do quite want you want. I did find a solution for you though, again, in 3.4.

Highlight the class, do a copy CTRL-C or cut CTRL-X, click on the package you want the class do go into, and do a paste, CTRL-V. Eclipse will auto generate the class for you.

Convert Member Type to Top Level doesn't quite work. Doing that will create a field of the outer class and generate a constructor that takes the outer class as a parameter.

Comment: So close.  That's exactly what I want, but paste is grayed in the package when I do that.  I wonder if my version of eclipse is too old.  3.3.1.1?

Comment: I just tested it in 3.3 and it did work. Hmm... maybe you missed copying the class line?

Comment: Got it!  Only works in Package Explorer, not Navigator.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Convert Member Type to Top Level works as intended if you're converting a static inner class. Otherwise, Eclipse doesn't know for certain that you don't need the outer instance.

Answer (score 37):

In Eclipse 3.6, you can do: Refactor -> Move type to new file

Comment: +1 This was exactly what I was looking for!  I had searched "eclipse extract inner class into outer class", this was the first question that came up, and this was the exact answer I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the class name (in the source code) and choose Refactor -> Convert Member Type to Top Level.  It doesn't let you choose the package, though.

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio: 
Refactor -> Move -> Move inner class MyInnerClass to upper level

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in 2 refactorings :

> 1. Convert Member type to top level
> 2. Move